# Como funcionam as pastas temporárias?

Tags: sistema-operacional, sistema-de-arquivos

Eu estive hoje me questionando a respeito disso. Tanto em sistemas operacionais Unix como Windows, temos um local específico onde são jogados arquivos temporários de toda espécie.

É óbvio pensar que, se a pasta é temporária, os dados ficarão ali apenas por determinado tempo.

Mas agora surgem várias dúvidas:

- Como e quando esses arquivos são removidos? Existe alguma configuração no sistema operacional quanto a isso?
- Tem alguma coisa a ver com a reinicialização do sistema? Se for, como fica o caso dos servidores, que geralmente são raramente reiniciados?
- Existe alguma forma de assinalar no sistema operacional (pelo menos no Windows e Linux) que outras pastas também serão consideradas temporárias?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depende de sistema operacional.

> Como e quando esses arquivos são removidos? Existe alguma configuração no sistema operacional quanto a isso?

No Windows não tem algo automático, deve remover manualmente. Limpar o que é temporário deve ser **responsabilidade da aplicação**. Colocar algo ali só quer dizer que ele pode desaparecer a qualquer momento sem controle da aplicação. Obviamente que se o arquivo estiver em uso ninguém poderá removê-lo.

No Linux depende do lugar onde coloca e da distribuição. No `/tmp`, embora seja recomendado apagar quando há *boot*, nada garante que seja feito na sua distribuição. No `var/tmp` fica o tempo que for necessário até alguma intervenção da aplicação ou do "dono" da máquina, igual ao Windows.

Se não adicionar uma aplicação específica para cuidar disso e sua aplicação não cuidar, em geral ele vai enchendo.

Isto é só uma convenção para não deixar arquivos temporários espalhados para todo lado e você saber que apagando ali se livra deles. Pena que muitos programadores ignoram essa recomendação e espalham arquivos para todo lado.

> Tem alguma coisa a ver com a reinicialização do sistema? Se for, como fica o caso dos servidores, que geralmente são raramente reiniciados?

Tem no Linux, mas de qualquer forma é problema seu resolver isso, então pouco importa se é um servidor.

> Existe alguma forma de assinalar no sistema operacional (pelo menos no Windows e Linux) que outras pastas também serão consideradas temporárias?

Que eu saiba não tem de forma padrão, mas no Linux sempre pode ser mexido se a pessoa quiser muito e for capacitada. E nem tem importância existir algo assim. O Windows permite mudar o local da pasta.

> Como usar esta pasta na minha aplicação?

Esta era a pergunta mais importante que não foi feita em um Q&A de programação.

No Linux é seguro sempre usar `/tmp` e `/var/tmp` para colocar seus arquivos temporários.

No Windows o correto é consultar onde a pasta está já que ela pode ser configurada pelo usuário (só pode existir uma), através de API disponibilizada na linguagem que está usando ou pela variável de ambiente `TEMP`.

Se não o fizer e achar que deve por em outro lugar pelo menos garanta a limpeza deles em qualquer circunstância, mesmo quando a aplicação quebra.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).